# Angular object array to column array

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq, angularjs

I have object, which has field `id` and `text` and possibly more other fields.

There are lots of objects in the array, and I want to convert it to a text array.

This is what I have at the moment. Any prettier solution, possible something LINQ like?

```
var emails = new Array();
angular.forEach(this.form.Emails, function (email) {
    emails.push(email.text);
});
```

Comment: You could use something like `underscore` and use their `map()` functions.  Another interesting choice can be seen here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411620/angular-equivalent-of-jquery-map

Comment: What is the problem with solution you posted above?

Comment: Extra 3 lines of code everytime I have to select a field from object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Nix answered you, you can use <kbd>[pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)</kbd> of Underscore library.

> extracting a list of property values

---

*Example:*

```
this.form.Emails = [
                    {text: 'moe', id: 1},
                    {text: 'larry', id: 2},
                    {text: 'curly', id: 3}
                   ];

var emails = _.pluck(this.form.Emails, 'text');

//ouput
 ["moe", "larry", "curly"]
```

Anyways I suggest you to leave your code version as is (aka `angular.forEach`). Because other programmer that maintains your code must know what `pluck` does.

*<sup>Make your code simple</sup>*