# Angular $filter select property only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

is there a built in way to use angular's **$filter** service to retrieve an array of containing only a specific property from an array of objects ?

```
var contacts = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      id: 42
    },
    {
      name: 'Mary',
      id: 43
    },
];

var ids = $filter('filter')(contacts, /* my magical parameter */);
console.log(ids); //output [42, 43]
```

Any help or link to a related topic would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: [`contacts.map(o => o.id);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bfx5qxww/)

Comment: show the code instead of `/* my magical parameter */` to clearly understand your question and your effort.

Comment: The `'filter'` filter will always return the full matching object. You need to create a custom filter. or just use vanilla javascript, like `map` as Tushar is suggesting

Comment: I didn't now the `'filter'` could only return the full matching object... I think i'll stick with Vanilla JS, looks like a great librairy ;-)

Comment: I guess this is the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411620/angular-equivalent-of-jquery-map

Comment: @Tushar your solution did worked, thanks a lot! If you'd like to give an answer with your suggestion, i'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @PierreRoudaut You can see similar answer below, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need use $filter service of angularjs,  you can use .map() method (core JS, I mean ES5):

```
var contacts = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      id: 42
    },
    {
      name: 'Mary',
      id: 43
    },
];

var ids = contacts.map(function(contact) {
   return contact.id;
});

console.log(ids); //output [42, 43]
```